# get custom class by element of custom class javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function city(circle,reinf)
        {
            this.reinf = reinf;
            this.circle.onmouseover = function(){
                alert(this.city);
            }   
        }
```

How to access the main city element and another element of city

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that *`this`* in `alert(this.city)` actually refers to the `this.circle` clicked element - therefore you need to control the `this` reference within your function. Here are three ways:

Using  **[`.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)**

```
function city(circle, reinf) {

    this.city = "Foo";
    this.circle = circle; // Forgot this one?
    this.reinf = reinf;

    this.circle.onmouseenter = function(){
        alert(this.city);
    }.bind(this);   // << bind to the outer this context
}
```

Storing `this` in a **variable**

```
function city(circle, reinf) {
    var self = this;

    this.city = "Foo";
    this.circle = circle;
    this.reinf = reinf;

    this.circle.onmouseenter = function(){
        alert(self.city);   // << refer to self
    }
}
```

Using [**Arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
function city(circle, reinf) {

    this.city = "Foo";
    this.circle = circle;
    this.reinf = reinf;

    this.circle.onmouseenter = () => { // << Arrow function with unbound this 
        alert(this.city);
    };
}
```

PS: you'll also not likely want to use `mouseover` - since it works pretty differently from `mouseenter`.